# Creating subplots with seaborn, filtered y values

Tags: python, seaborn, linear-regression, subplot

I have this plot:

[image]

Which I am plotting using:

```
import pydove as dv

#Read in proper dataframe
intensity = pd.read_csv('filtered_storm_vmax_real.csv', sep = ',', header= 0 ) 
print(intensity.head(5))

#Define variables for linear regression - intensity
x_col ='season'
y_col ='vmax'
x = intensity[x_col]
y = intensity[y_col]
x_array = np.array(x).reshape(-1,1)
y_array = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid", color_codes="ch:start=.2,rot=-.3")
sns.color_palette("ch:start=.2,rot=-.3", as_cmap=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
res = dv.regplot(x,y, ax=ax,scatter=True, scatter_kws={'alpha':0.25})
plt.setp(ax.collections[1], alpha=0.5)
ax.set_xlabel('Season')
ax.set_ylabel('Intensity of Storm (max wind in knots)')
ax.set_title('Intensity of Storms Over Time')
```

And I want to create subplots with linear regressions (like the main plot) but only show the following y-axis value intervals:

0-40
40-80
80-120
120-160

I tried to use Seaborn's FacetGrid like so:

```
col_ordered = ['1','2','3','4']
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=intensity, col='subplot', col_order= col_ordered, sharex='row' ,height=1.7, aspect=4)
```

But didn't result in the proper y value intervals. Plots were also horizontal instead of stacked on top of one another as I am aiming for.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `sns.FacetGrid(..., row='subplot', row_order=..., sharex='col')` for rows instead of columns?  You could try `pd.cut` on `'vmax'` to create the `'subplot'`column.  You could try `sns.relplot(data='intensity', x='season', y='vmax', row='subplot', row_order=...)` to let seaborn create the plot in one go.   Note that `sns.color_palette("ch:start=.2,rot=-.3", as_cmap=True)` should be assigned to a variable and then used as parameter in `dv.regplot` or `sns.relplot`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @JohanC. I ended up working around using matplotlib axes but your answer was still super informative. Also good tip about the color palette!